# Connecting to AS400 with Django using ibm-db-django

Tags: python, django, database, db2, connection

I am trying to connect my newly created django project to an AS400 system that already has a lot of data stored on it. The only documentation I can find on how to configure your Django project is on [this github page](https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb-django) and goes over how to set up your virtual environment and get all necessary dependencies and versions.

Currently I have my package versions set up according to that documentation as seen here

```
Package           Version
----------------- --------
asgiref           3.7.2
Django            3.2
ibm-db            3.1.4
ibm-db-django     1.5.2.0
pip               22.0.4
pyodbc            4.0.39
pytz              2023.3
regex             2023.6.3
setuptools        58.1.0
six               1.16.0
sqlparse          0.4.4
typing_extensions 4.7.1
```

My current python version is also `Python 3.10.4`.
I also have the my database setting within my settings.py folder set up like this

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
     'ENGINE'     : 'ibm_db_django',
     'NAME'       : '_____',
     'USER'       : '_____',
     'PASSWORD'   : '_____',
     'HOST'       : '_____',
     'PORT'       : '_____',
     'PCONNECT'   : True,
  }
}
```

And I know all the values for these settings are in fact connect since I am able to connect to the AS400 system when using the PYODBC library which requires a connection string with the same data in order to access the AS400 system.

```
# Define the connection string
connection_string = 'DRIVER={IBM i Access ODBC Driver};SYSTEM=_____;UID=_____;PWD=_____'
```

However, I would like to connect properly using the actual database settings since this is much more efficient vs using the PYODBC method. Whenever I try and run the following commands:

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations

python3 manage.py migrate
```

My command line just seems to get stuck in place and I get no feedback, I am not sure if this is actually establishing a connection and it is just taking a lot time since there is already a lot of data on the AS400 I am connecting to that needs to be processed?
Whenever I try and quit these commands with ^C, my terminal still does nothing and I need to manually quit the terminal and restart.

Whenever I run the following runserver command, I get this response:

```
(env) floriskruger4@Floriss-MacBook-Pro myproj % python3 manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
```

Usually you would get another message after this stating that the **development has started on a server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/** or something like that. But my terminal just stops at system checks and I am not able to access the web page.

Does anyone know if this connection is actually established or how I can check if the command line commands are actually processing the data on the AS400 system and that is why my terminal is in fact "stuck" or just taking a long time? Or is it actually stuck and I need to change my approach?

Comment: The support channel for ibm_db_django is on github at github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb-django/issues . However, its README states that only Db2-LUW is currently supported. While pyodbc+IBM i access driver is a known working configuration, I don't know if ibm_db is able to use the IBM i access odbc driver (instead it will use , by default, the clidriver, which needs a licence to connect to i series). It's unclear how you have configured your ibm_db. Use the trace facilitity of the underlying driver to see what's happening.

Comment: I ended up switching to a windows laptop and configured everything on there. I was also able to get all three drivers installed:
Client Access ODBC Driver (32-bit)
IBM i Access ODBC Drive
iSeries Access ODBC Driver 

And yes you are correct, the default driver ibm_db uses is the Client Access Driver. However, I am still faced with the same problem and not getting any feedback when running the commands to connect. Also, my trace facility is not writing anything to the files... This must mean that the ODBC driver is not really being used? I'm completely stumped...

Comment: Open a ticket at  https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb-django/issues   Be prepared to give all factual details, exact steps you took when installing and configuring.   This is not a matter for stackoverflow.